# hot to creat a restful web service for MVC & use it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, rest

I am working in asp.net mvc & want to create a restful web service.
Can you please let me know how can i create a restful web service in MVC & how can i use it ?
My requirement is :
i have an application server which send some parameters to web service & the web service should connect to remote server & return image on path (whose path will be generated by the parameters from application server).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some articles you might read:

- [ASP.NET MVC: Using RESTful Architecture](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2007/12/06/aspnet-mvc-using-restful-architecture)
- [RESTful Services With ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943053.aspx)
- [Simply Restful Routing in MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting&referringTitle=Documentation&ProjectName=mvccontrib)